# How to convert mongodb document to JSON string?

Tags: mongodb, rust

I am using mongodb rust driver, But I don't know how to convert `mongodb::bson::Document` to JSON format.

```rs
let document: mongodb::bson::Document = client
    .database("demo")
    .collection("folder")
    .find_one(doc!{})
    .await?
    .unwrap();

println("{:?}", document); // How to convert `document` to json string?
```

I want to send this JSON string from server as response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mongodb::bson::Document` implements `Serialize` from [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde), so you can use [`serde_json::to_string`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.64/serde_json/fn.to_string.html), or other functions from [`serde_json`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) to serialize the data to JSON.

Comment: I looked into `serde_json::to_string`, And an example would be very helpfull

Comment: In this example, you would want to do something like:
`println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&document).unwrap());`

Comment: There is also `serde_json::to_string_pretty` which will pretty-print the data which I assume you may want.